# How to check if application with particular package name is already installed in device

Tags: android

Is there any way to check if the particular application is already installed in device ? May be through some package name ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
public void checkApplication(String packageName) {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = null;
    try {
        applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (applicationInfo == null) {
        // not installed
    } else {
        // Installed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this:

add `packagename` in `targetPackage` of checking application .

```
public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
        PackageManager pm;
            pm = getPackageManager();        
            packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage)) return true;
        }        
        return false;
    }
```